# What is the number of people that could NOT be standing on this line?

Tags: contest-math, combinations

> A number of people are standing in a line in such a way that each person is next to exactly one person who is wearing a hat. Which of the following could not be the number of people standing on the line:
>
> a) 98
> b) 99
> c) 100
> d) 101
> e) 102

-Question 23, Junior Division AMC 2016

---

The first combination which came to my mind was:

> H,H,N,N,H,H,N,N...

Where H is someone who's wearing a hat and N is someone who is not wearing a hat.

The way one of these options could NOT be a possibility is if two people of the same kind are left out:

> H,H,N,N,H,H

or

> H,H,N,N

So how do I go about this? I think it has to do something about even possibilities but I'm not sure.

P.S. Please explain this using Year 7, 8 & 9 math concepts

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly observed, you can have a pattern like HHNNHHNNHH. With a bit of fiddling with the possibilities I think you can convince yourself that the "HHNN" pattern is the only pattern you /can/ have. The only except is how you end it.

How many people are in such a line? Well, we start with the simplest pattern, just "HH", and add people in multiples of 4 (HHNN). This means we can get even numbers of people, but not the multiples of 4. (If you've seen modular arithmetic, we can state it as numbers congruent to 2, mod 4.) This means we can get lines of 98 or 102.

Furthermore, once we have a line that goes HHNNHHNN...HH, we have H's at either end, so we can add an N to one or both ends. This means we can get 99 people (by adding just one, NHHNN...HH) or 100 people (by adding both, NHHNN...HHN).

That's enough to answer the problem, so of the ones given, only 101 isn't possible!